# PHP53_via_FastCGI error 0xc0000005 in Windows Azure WebRole

Tags: php, windows, azure, iis-7.5, fastcgi

I don't why, but after 6h of searching the bug, I can't identify it.
It appear somewhere deep in the framework code when tring to include a dynamic file path.

When I try to do the exctly same include call on a different place, die IIS Error doesn't appear.

phpinfo() works fine, my application not.

The IIS error:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
>
> Module FastCgiModule  Notification ExecuteRequestHandler  Handler
>   PHP53_via_FastCGI  Error Code 0xc0000005

PHP 5.3.9 nts on IIS 7.5

I already red tons of articles about this error, nothing helped. 
It's funny, because yesterday everything was fine.

Maybe you can give me a helpful hint.

**Edit:**

It seems I found the reasons for the problem:

**1.** After deployment into the Azure cloud, some process adds a whole copy of the php.ini to the end of the existing php.ini file. So I get a lot of warings from php-cgi.

-> This was done by the startup task. I'm wondering why the task now enhances everything instead of overwriting as before.

**2.** I saw that there is a new PHP Version for Windows 5.3.9 (Build date Jan 10 2012 16:30:15). You can also find it over MS Web Platform Installer. I currently use 5.3.8 (Build date Aug 23 2011 12:11:54). I have it in Program files and also in my WebRole folder. Normally the startup task takes my version out of the WebRole folder but newly it doesn't. When I change the paths over RDP, everthings works well.

Now I just need to find a way to enforce Azure to take the PHP in my package.

Comment: try to passthrough http errors from the php to see the actual error from the php. Check this post for how to do that: http://blogs.staykov.net/2010/06/display-php-error-messages-on-iis-70-75.html it may help identifying the issue. Also try enabling errors in the php.ini (i.e.  “display_errors=on" and “error_reporting=E_ALL”)

Comment: Did you try showing the actual error following the steps on my blog post? Did you have any success with this issue?

Comment: Have you checked any of the following resources for the same error:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45786 
http://forums.iis.net/t/1159556.aspx 
http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?t=133102

Comment: @astaykov: The PHP errors are already turned on. And can see the real IIS error (s.a.) because I can call the site from the instance (localhost). And I already have have these php.ini settings. I really don't don't want to get back to PHP 5.2. Last week everything was fin with the system.

Comment: But this the IIS error. The point is to get to the PHP error.

Comment: I did all settings to get PHP errors, but I don't get any :/

Comment: I found the problem, check the post update.

Comment: @ownking, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Charles, but it is not the solution, it's just the reason. I don't want to change always the paths manually with RDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to bypass this error. I explained it here: http://blog.itopia.de/windows-azure-custom-php-installation/366

But I still don't know why PHP 5.3.9 create this error and 5.3.8 not...

Comment: This just happened to my php on azure/iis for php 7.2 (5/12/18)